# Javascript - Remember Selected Option

Tags: javascript, sorting, select

I have a webpage thats created by javascript injections and one of my pages has a dropdown shown below:

```
html +="<select name='Sort' id='Sort' onchange='sortSwitch(document.getElementById(\"Sort\")[document.getElementById(\"Sort\").selectedIndex].value);     display(document.getElementById(\"searchQuery\").value);return false;'>\n";  
  html +="<option></option>\n";  
  html +="<option value='4'>Smallest First</option>\n";  
  html +="<option value='5'>Largest First</option>\n";  
  html +="<option value='6'>A-Z</option>\n";  
  html +="<option value='7'>Z-A</option>\n";  
  html +="</select>";
```

The dropdown filters the information displayed on the page by passing the selected option to a switch function and another function reloads this information. However, when the javascript page loads again, it starts off with the blank option.

Does anyone know of a good way to remember the last sort selected? For example, if I sort with "Smallest First" and then the page refreshes, the box will show "Smallest First" as apposed to the blank. I know there is an "option selected" attribute, but I need it to be dynamic. I feel like it is something trivial, yet I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an article on [**Cookies in JavaScript**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) which contains an explanation of how they work, along with functions to read, write and delete cookies.

Using those functions you'd get the selected value and **write the cookie** to save the value like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("Sort");
var selectedItem = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
createCookie("selectedItem",selectedItem);
```

then **read the cookie** to retrieve the value and select the `option` in the `select` box, like this:

```
var selectedItem = readCookie("selectedItem");
var select = document.getElementById("Sort");
select.value = selectedItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cookies. or some session variables on the server side to save the values that were selected.

I use [this jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)