# Javascript remember selected option value from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, load, selected

Doing a bit of research I now know I have to write the cookie of the selected option. then read the cookie to retrieve the value.

I found a similar question but couldn't figure out how to implement the code from the  answer

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996261/javascript-remember-selected-option)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>dropdown remember selection test</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="stream_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="854"   height="480" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" name="stream_iframe" src="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay"></iframe> 

<form> 
<select name="options" onchange="document.getElementById('stream_iframe').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option>SELECT STREAM
<option value="https://streamup.com/rooms/jumanjijoes-Channel/plugins/video/show?startMuted=false">Jumanjijoe</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/whenlinkattacks">Whenlinkattacks</option>
<option value="https://streamup.com/rooms/docblus-Channel/plugins/video/show?startMuted=false">Docblu</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/karenwaifu">Karenmaiwaifu</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/ninjatart">Nightsanity</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/frightfest0001">Frightfest0001</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/anime_hq">Anime HQ</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay">MovieBay</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/freakyfetish101">Horror Movie</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv//embed/video/111aaacharkmovies">111aaacharkmovies </option> 
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I managed to create a dropdown menu that will change the iframe SRC. I just need it to remember what they select on refresh or browser exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this when user selects the value store the value to either local/or session storage of your browser and when user reopens first check whether local storage has the value or not if yes select the value using jquery.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

You can see how to use local storage at  w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Edited:

Find Complete code Here

```
<iframe id="stream_iframe" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="854" height="480" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" name="stream_iframe" src="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay"></iframe> 

<form> 
<select name="options" onchange="callMe(this);" id="selectMovie">
<option>SELECT STREAM
<option value="https://streamup.com/rooms/jumanjijoes-Channel/plugins/video/show?startMuted=false">Jumanjijoe</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/whenlinkattacks">Whenlinkattacks</option>
<option value="https://streamup.com/rooms/docblus-Channel/plugins/video/show?startMuted=false">Docblu</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/karenwaifu">Karenmaiwaifu</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/ninjatart">Nightsanity</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/frightfest0001">Frightfest0001</option> 
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/anime_hq">Anime HQ</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/moviebay">MovieBay</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv/embed/video/freakyfetish101">Horror Movie</option>
<option value="http://vaughnlive.tv//embed/video/111aaacharkmovies">111aaacharkmovies </option> 
</select>
</form>
<script>
function callMe(obj){
localStorage.setItem("selectedStream",obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value);
document.getElementById('stream_iframe').src = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
}
document.getElementById("stream_iframe").src = localStorage.getItem("selectedStream");
document.getElementById("selectMovie").value = ""+localStorage.getItem("selectedStream")+"";
</script>
```

Comment: I know I have to store the values problem is i don't know how with a form
would it be something like this?


// Store
localStorage.setItem("selectedStream", "value");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("stream_iframe").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("selectedStream");

Comment: I haved added the complete code. Copy it to html file and run it on browser.

Comment: Thank you looking through the code i understand it better now thank you. the src becomes null at first run though.