# How Javascript remembers user's selection from drop-down list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list of items.
What i want is when user clicks on one item of the list, when returns to gui to select something, the system should 'remember' user's past choice.
What do i have to consider in order to develop this?
I am including a simple code for this attempt.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var locations = {
        'Office': [ 'Rome','Milano', 'New York', 'Portland', 'Paris', 'San Francisco'],
        'Country': [ 'CA', 'FR', 'IT', 'US'],
    }

    var $locations = $('#element');
    $('#attribute').change(function () {
        var attribute = $(this).val(), lcns = locations[attribute] || [];

        var html = $.map(lcns, function(lcn){
            return '<option value="' + lcn + '">' + lcn + '</option>'
        }).join('');
        $locations.html(html)
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label class="page1">Attribute</label>
<div class="tooltips" title="Please select the attribute that the customer will primarily be served from">
    <select id="attribute" name="attribute" placeholder="Phantasyland">
        <option></option>
        <option>Office</option>
        <option>Country</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<label class="page1">List of elements</label>
<div class="tooltips" title="Please select the city that the customer is primarily to be served from.">
    <select id="element" name="element" placeholder="Anycity"></select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript remember selected option value from dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118922/javascript-remember-selected-option-value-from-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 2):

You could use browser storage to store what user selected in his session.

The following url contains the documentation for the localstorage api.

[MDN : Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**example**

*to store items :*

```
localStorage.setItem('yourItem', 'Value');
```

*to retrieve stored items :*

```
localStorage.getItem("yourItem");
```

*to delete a stored item :*

```
localStorage.removeItem("yourItem");
```

The above examples will only give you an understanding of how to use the localstorage. You would need to add them to the appropriate location of your code where the relevant actions are happening.

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I updated my answer to give a basic usage understanding. Thank you for pointing out my error.